# Вызгрузка файла в докер

Tags: java, docker

Всем привет,я новичок в использовании докера. Есть написанный автотест JUnit, после прогона автотеста формируется файл log.txt.Есть настроенный докер, возможно ли с помощью мавен команды выгрузить этот лог в докер?

Comment: Какое приложение запущено в докер-контейнере? Какое поведение вы хотите получить?

Comment: Как правило автотесты пишутся таким образом, чтобы при негативном сценарии тест падал, и не нужно было в логах что-то искать. Напишите более подробно, что вы тестируете?